# How to use FileTable in EF Code First

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, filetable

I'm using `FileTable` in SQL Server 2014 and EF code first in my project.

When I use this command

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [OnlineStore] 
SET FILESTREAM( DIRECTORY_NAME = N'OnlineStore',
    NON_TRANSACTED_ACCESS = FULL) WITH NO_WAIT
GO
```

it shows this warning in sql

> When the FILESTREAM database option NON_TRANSACTED_ACCESS is set to FULL and the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT or the ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION options are on, T-SQL and transactional read access to FILESTREAM data in the context of a FILETABLE is blocked.

Now I continue and create the table, and insert folder and file not problem.

My problem to read data, when read data is show this error:

> Msg 33447, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Cannot access file_stream column in FileTable 'File', because FileTable doesn't support row versioning. Either set transaction level to something other than READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT or SNAPSHOT, or use READCOMMITTEDLOCK table hint.

I'm using EF code first - how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Tanx For Edited Question

Comment: Entity Framework currently does not support FileTable due to lack of support for hierarchyid, before you go on, you should probably research that.

Answer (score 6):

You must run this command to have the ability to SELECT the table.
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [dbname] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF WITH NO_WAIT